# Separable partial differential equation solving it

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How does the

$X"= 0$ and $Y'= 0$

is solved through integration and you get

$$X= C_1 + C_2x$$

$$Y = C_3$$

Comment: not a pde. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: the derivative of a constant is zero.

Comment: From the Advanced engineering mathematics 5th edition book, they are talking about chapter 13.1: Separation of partial differential equations along with other topics including heat and wave equations. I am having trouble solving a given PDE using separable equations then solve for u(x,y) = XY using the three cases where lamda= 0, lambda= -α^2 and lamda=α^2.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not easily understood, but from your comment I believe the following helps.

We will consider the PDE $u_t = u_{xx}$. Similar approaches will work with the wave equation.  We use separation of variables and assume that $u$ can be represented as

$$u(x,t) = X(x)Y(t).$$

Plugging in this form of $u$ into the PDE we get:

$$X(x) Y'(t) = X''(x) Y(t).$$

Rearranging:

$$\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)} = \frac{Y'(t)}{Y(t)}.$$

Note that this equation must hold for all $x$ and all $t$, and so it must be the case that it is constant:

$$\frac{X''}{X} = \frac{Y'}{Y} = -\lambda.$$

Thus I get two ODEs to solve:

$$X'' +\lambda X = 0,$$

and

$$Y' + \lambda Y =0.$$

Now, you can consider the three cases: $\lambda>0, \lambda<0, \lambda=0$ and use methods from ODEs to finish the problem.

EDIT: The three cases come into play for the equation of $X$:

**Case 1.** $\lambda =-\alpha^2<0$. Then $X'' -\alpha^2 X =0$ has characteristic equation $z^2-\alpha^2 = 0$. The roots are $z=\pm \alpha$ so we have general solution

$$X(x) = C_1e^{\sqrt{-\lambda}x} + C_2 e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda}x}.$$

The equation for $Y$ is easily solved:

$$Y(t) = C_3e^{-\lambda t}.$$

**Case 2.** $\lambda = \alpha^2 >0$. The characteristic equation of $X$ is $z^2+\alpha^2=0$, which has roots $z = \pm \alpha i.$ The general solution for $X$ is then

$$X(x) = C_1 \sin{\lambda x} +C_2 \cos{\lambda x},$$

and the equation for $Y$ is still $Y(t) = C_3e^{-\lambda t}.$

**Case 3.** $\lambda =0 $.  The equations for $X$ and $Y$ can be explicitly integrated:

$$X''=0 \Rightarrow X'(x)  = C_2 \Rightarrow X(x) = C_1 + C_2x,$$

and likewise

$$Y' = 0 \Rightarrow Y(t) = C_3.$$

Comment: That's the problem, I don't understand the three cases (and everything else above is fine).  For example, if λ ≠ 0 and we have to solve for λyY' - 1 = 0 and X' + λx =0. The book says X= C1e^(-λx) and Y= C2y^(1/λ). If the case of λ= 0 we get that it yields no solution. I think these are properties to memorize but I don't know how they get these two answers (for X and Y)

Comment: I don't understand the equations you have. What was your PDE? Given what you have written, if $\lambda =0 $ then there is no hope of solving the equation for $Y$. There is no reason to memorize these properties, if you plug in $\lambda =0 $ the equation for $Y$ degenerates to $-1=0$, which is obviously wrong.